# Unwanted white-spaces after printing arrays. I am using perl

Tags: perl, excel, vim, whitespace, text-parsing

I wrote a script to parse an input text file and output three new text files. The input file has a header line, which is left out of each of the three output files. Each line of the output files gets the first three entries of every input file line, then gets only a portion of the entries in the input line. All files are tab delimited.

My problem is that I keep getting an extra white-space at the end of my output lines. I can see this white-space at the end of the lines of my output files when viewing in VIM. I can't see these extra white-spaces when viewing in excel.

Previously, using an earlier version of my script, I could see extra white-space at the end of my lines using excel, but only by using the "select all" feature. The data displayed in excel was the result of my perl script printing an array, where I coded `print $outfile "@array"`. I learned elsewhere on stackoverflow that typing `print "@array"` causes a kind of interpolation that adds in white-spaces to my lines. White-spaces resulting from this interpolation were not immediately visible in excel, but could be seen when "select all" was used to highlight the data. So, I changed my code from `print $outfile "@array"` to `print $outfile @array`. This change results in output files that still maintain a white-space at the end of each output line, a white-space visible in VIM but not in excel. This is where I am stuck.

Here is my script below. The first part just opens and reads the input file. Then some arrays are declared. Next, a `for loop` is begun to begin parsing the input file line by line, and pushing appropriate content into appropriate arrays. A substitution is implemented for one array. Again, all files are tab delimited. Finally, the arrays are printed to three outfiles, using the phrasing `print $outfile @array` and not `print $outfile "@array"`.

Do you see the problem? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

die "usage: [ imputed genotype.file ]\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

my $imputed = $ARGV[ 0 ];
open ( my $FILE, "<$imputed" );
my @data  = <$FILE>; 

my @ADD = ();
my @DOM = ();
my @IMP = ();

for ( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @data; $i++ ) ### for each line data[i], and use $i = 1 to
                                           ### skip header, 0 to include it output
    {
     my $line = $data[ $i ];
     chomp $line;

     my @entries = split( '\t', $data[ $i ] );

     push( @ADD, "$entries[ 0 ]\t$entries[ 1 ]\t$entries[ 2 ]\t" );
     push( @DOM, "$entries[ 0 ]\t$entries[ 1 ]\t$entries[ 2 ]\t" );
     push( @IMP, "$entries[ 0 ]\t$entries[ 1 ]\t$entries[ 2 ]\t" );

     for ( my $i = 3; $i < scalar @entries - 1 ; $i+=3 ) ### for each entry per line
         {
          push( @ADD, "$entries[ $i ]\t" );
          push( @DOM, "$entries[ $i + 1 ]\t" );

          if ( $entries[ $i + 2 ] eq 'NA' ) ### to replace any occuring "NA"s with blanks
             {
              $entries[ $i + 2 ] =~ s/NA//; 
             }

          push( @IMP, "$entries[ $i + 2 ]\t" );
          }

    push( @ADD, "\n" ); 
    push( @DOM, "\n" );
    push( @IMP, "\n" ); 

   } ### for loop   

open my $Afile, ">$imputed" . "_ADD.txt" or die $!;
print $Afile @ADD; 
close $Afile;

open my $Dfile, ">$imputed" . "_DOM.txt" or die $!;
print $Dfile @DOM;
close $Dfile;

open my $Ifile, ">$imputed" . "_IMP.txt" or die $!;
print $Ifile @IMP;
close $Ifile;
```

Comment: what is the significance of the double vs single quotes? in my review of the use of split, usually single quotes `' '` are used (or `/ /`, depending on context).

Comment: Double quotes interpolate variables within the string.  Single quotes do not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem in using \t at the end of the array element. Use function

```
join( "\t", ...)
```

instead.

I mean, just create output array, and then use

```
print join "\t", @output;
```

There is untested example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

die "usage: [ imputed genotype.file ]\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

open my $Afile, ">$imputed" . "_ADD.txt" or die $!;
open my $Dfile, ">$imputed" . "_DOM.txt" or die $!;
open my $Ifile, ">$imputed" . "_IMP.txt" or die $!;

<>; #skip header
while(<>){ 
      chomp;
      my @entries = split( '\t', $_ );

      my @ADD = ();
      my @DOM = ();
      my @IMP = ();

      push( @ADD, $entries[ 0 ], $entries[ 1 ], $entries[ 2 ]);
      push( @DOM, $entries[ 0 ], $entries[ 1 ], $entries[ 2 ]);
      push( @IMP, $entries[ 0 ], $entries[ 1 ], $entries[ 2 ]);

      for ( my $i = 3; $i < scalar @entries - 1 ; $i+=3 ) { ### for each entry per line
          push( @ADD, $entries[ $i ] );
          push( @DOM, $entries[ $i + 1 ] );

      $entries[ $i + 2 ] =~ s/^NA$//; 

          push( @IMP, $entries[ $i + 2 ] );
      }

      print $Afile join( "\t", @ADD) , "\n"; 
      print $Dfile join( "\t", @DOM) , "\n"; 
      print $Ifile join( "\t", @IMP) , "\n"; 

} ### for loop   

close $Afile;
close $Dfile;
close $Ifile;
```

Comment: can you be a little more explicit? could you guide me where the join command should go? i put it in my final `print` statements as `print $Afile join "\t", @ADD;`. But this scrambled things up.

Comment: You can make join( "\t", ...) for every element in the row, and join( "\n", ...) for every row, or just print output row by row with "\n" at the end of the row.

Comment: i still don't understand. could you embed your idea into the code above?

Comment: push( @ADD, $entries[ $i ] );

Comment: print $Afile join( "\t", @ADD);

Comment: if i want to push multiple $entries into the array at a particular step, can i type `push( @ADD, $entries[ $i ],$entries[ $i +1 ], $entries[ $i + 2] );`?

Comment: Yes, you can push list of entries to array: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html

Comment: still getting a white-space at the end. i changed each instance of `push( @ADD...)` and still a white-space.

Comment: wow, @user1883592, thanks! that works. plus, it is so much faster in while running my text files. maybe it is about twice as fast.  the only thing i need to add was an explicit package name for "imputed" by declaring `my $imputed = $ARGV[0];`. Otherwise, it looks like it is working. And I also learned some other tricks, too. Thanks!

Comment: Try AWK, it's even faster for this kind of probmem.

Comment: so, @user1883592, if I wanted to make my outfiles .csv files, I am seeing that changing all the `join( "\t", @arrays)` to `join( ",", @arrays)` doesn't quite work. I get two extra commas at the end. Do you see why?

Comment: Only if you have an empty values in last columns in input file.

Comment: Hi @user1883592, so it kind of seems like I have now come full circle. That is, I started with a problem where I was getting additional and unwanted white-space at the ends of my lines. Thank you for helping me that! However, in trying to use commas, instead of tabs, to make a cvs type file, I am finding two additional spaces at the ends of my lines. The input file is "clean", in that it has no further characters or white-spaces after its lines, which I checked using both excel and VIM. How else might they enter? I can send you input file if you have time and patience to see.

Answer (score 2):

```
push( @ADD, "$entries[ 0 ]\t$entries[ 1 ]\t$entries[ 2 ]\t" );
```

These lines always add a tab at the end, which is probably what you're seeing.  Also, consider using a `join` and an array slice instead of string interpolation, like:

```
push( @ADD, join( "\t", @entries[0..2] ) );
```

Comment: i think i see that working for the first three elements that go into my arrays. how would you use the `join` in the second `for loop`, the one embedded in the first loop?

Comment: hey, @frezik, shouldn't that be `join( '\t'` instead of `join( "\t" ` ?

Comment: @eric - frezik is correct, else you'd be `join`ing using the string literal `'\t'` and not a tab character.

Comment: hi @kenosis, but I have been using `'\t'` and it has been tab delimiting my entries for me. My data are numeric, and so there are no t's to split with. Plus, most examples of `join` I see online use single quotes.